# Tuple vs array in hashtable Python

Tags: python

I have heard that tuple element take low space but can't be modify, so what is the best solution in terms of execution times:

```
hash = {}
hash['foo'] = [34,'foobar',[55,90]]
hash['foo'][0] = hash['foo'][0] + 17
```

OR

```
hash = {}
hash['foo'] = (34,'foobar',[55,90])
hash['foo'] = (hash['foo'][0] + 17,hash['foo'][1],hash['foo'][2])
```

Comment: 1.  Don't micro-optimize like this.  2.  Provide some requirements.  Without any requirements for what is supposed to happen, **all** data structures are equally good.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, don't call the dictionary `hash`. It shadows the built-in [hash](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#hash).

In both the cases, if you delete the last line and then time the code, the values are:

```
0.545173168182    # list
0.479876995087    # tuple
```

And that is expected behaviour. Because creating a `tuple` is faster than creating a list.

```
$ python -mtimeit 'l=[]'
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.053 usec per loop
$ python -mtimeit 't=()'
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.026 usec per loop
```

But in your case, take the third line. You create a new `foo` key as you can't modify the `tuple`, so it will take more time than the `list` example.

```
0.911674976349  # list
1.1165189743    # tuple
```

Another note, the time differences are micro-optimizations. Given the small difference, you should not worry about them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Even if I will modify more than 1,000,000 of tuple/list :)? My dictionary is huge

Comment: @John: Possibly, that is for you to [timeit](http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html) now :-)

Comment: @sukhir Great! i will do it and post my results here! Thanks!

Comment: But if you intend to change the value, having it is a `list` is recommended. Sure a `tuple` is created faster, but modifying it later is not what a `tuple` is for. Use a `list` for such a purpose. That is the right way to do it, optimizations apart.

Comment: I agree, but execution time is critical for me

Comment: Even then, the `list` version will be faster as you can modify the value without creating a new key.